# Docker - Angular container only displays nginx default page

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

Does Angular have any specific nginx configuration it needs? I'm having trouble getting my page to display; only the nginx page displays.

I have this exact setup for my React frontend container, and they display just fine, so I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Dockerfile:

```
# Stage 1: create build
FROM node:16-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./member-dashboard/package*.json .
COPY ./member-dashboard .
RUN npm i --legacy-peer-deps
RUN npm run build --prod

# Stage 2: host using nginx
FROM nginx:alpine
ARG PORT
ENV PORT=${PORT}
COPY --from=build /app/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE ${PORT} 80
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you get a shell inside your container with `docker run -it <image name> sh`, then run `ls -l /usr/share/nginx/html`, and post the output?

Comment: I see a section that says drwxr | 3 | root | root | 4096 | Jun | 2 | 22:37 | aline-member-dashboard.

Comment: Was the original nginx `index.html` replaced, or is the new `index.html` inside that directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do was re-order my first stage's build commands and refresh the page, and the index appeared just fine. Really weird issue, though.